# Unable to set up an OpenID login from WordPress

Tags: support, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I am attempting to use WordPress as my OpenID provider. I select the WP icon and when I click on "add credential" the OpenID URL is set to `http://{user}.wordpress.com/`. This takes me to the WordPress site, where I am logged in and have access to my account there, but it does not return me to Stack Exchange.

I have tried the setup from two Stack Exchange sites with similar results. I have tried the `https:` version with the same result. My userid, alias {user} here, is the same as my old Verisign one — I will delete that first if that's likely to be the problem.

I didn't see any prior question that gives me ideas. I conclude that there is an incompatibility between WordPress and Stack Exchange. Perhaps WP needs a subdomain which is not present here? Verisign used `pip.` specifically for OpenID. Can anyone verify if WP OpenID works for them? Otherwise, Stack Exchange may need to repair the interface or I may need to find an OpenID provider that works.

Of course, this only came up because Verisign will soon cancel their service.

Comment: Is using a bigger credential provider (Google/Facebook or our own) at all an option? I'll see what's going on with Wordpress, but in terms of reliability, you can't really beat the top three used providers in the SE network.

Comment: Yes, I will probably sign up directly with SE once Symatec cancels their service if I can't get WordPress working. It appears there is little incentive for companies to  provide  openid as a free service; Thanks, SE, for being one of the ones that do.

Comment: I found this question because I'm having the same problem.
In the Wordpress site though they say they do not provide OpenID anymore for new blogs (and mine is): https://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/openid/

Comment: @dowhile0 ok, case closed. SE appears to be the best openid provider around now.

Comment: @Adam why not remove WordPress from the list of providers?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It still works... sometimes. I'll bring it up on a team call, though, since it causes more and more problems.

Comment: @Adam I see, thanks. Any chance to nudge WordPress support about it? Coming from Stack Exchange they might pay more attention than to single users. :)

Answer (score 2):

Problem: WordPress is listed as an OpenId provider, but signing up with them and trying to use it gives no result.

Explanation: WordPress does not provide OpenId service to new blog owners since early 2016.

According to their support information, OpenId service has been discontinued. Thanks to dowhile0:

https://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/openid/

> OpenID is not available for any new blogs created after 2016-01-02. Blogs created before that date can use OpenID.

Unfortunately, WP provides no error indication when someone tries to use an OpenId that does not exist. The browser will simply go to the WP account (requesting login if necessary) and remain at the account page instead of returning to the requesting SE page.

Answer (score -2):

The above answer by @bitchaser is incomplete/Incorrect cause my WP-site/blog is way older than 2016/01 and still the OpenID for StackExchange does not work.

The Answers and some of the comments here claim that blogs created before 2016/01 "can use OpenID (for StackExchange) which is false.

Also the fact I have reported a relevant problem/issue to this problem shouldn't have been downvoted.

Comment: It doesn't work because you try to add it as new login to Stack Exchange. It doesn't matter when you created the original WordPress account itself. If you would have added it before 2016, you probably could still keep  using it to login to Stack Exchange.

Comment: In that case the Answers provided here are still incorrect because they only talk about blogs created after 2016/01 and not blogs added for OpenID/StackExchange login after 2016/01.

Comment: It's wordpress.com itself that claims that it should work, the answer here is simply quoting that.

Comment: @LXCdevKohaLappi you can't add blogs to Stack Exchange. You simply miss the concept of OpenID, and how it works.

Comment: I'm not 'adding a blog' but trying to add WP-based OpenID logins to StackExchange account. You have serious problems understanding user issues and your comments and voting behaviour is rude and arrogant. Still most of the Answers here are not fully and correctly addressing the issue which is the lack of support for OpenID/Wordpress in StackExchange accounts.

Comment: @LXCdevKohaLappi how doesn't it work? What happens when you try, do you get an error message? Is it stated anywhere that is doesn't work? Can you show us that it doesn't work? The previous answer here quotes an official source saying that it does work, so simply saying "it doesn't work" isn't of much help to anyone.

Comment: This should have been an edit to your original question to indicate why it wasn't a duplicate.  You should delete this and return to your question and update it.

Comment: Used to be that logging in with Wordpress accounts that didn't have a custom domain would work. Maybe that broke somewhere along the line too. I'll raise WP on a team call, though honestly the only course of action here is to either remove it as a supported provider or leave it in whatever state it's in now. We've made no changes on our end, so whatever's breaking is likely on Wordpress at this point.